# Upload files updated on CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

happy new year everyone.

I'm a little confused in the process of the updated data. This is my controller in codeigniter

```
function Ubah($id_pengetahuan) {
    $data['page_title'] = 'Ubah Pengetahuan';

    $ses_id = $this->session->id_pengguna;

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> PESAN : </strong>', '</div>');

    $error_msg = array('required' => '%s yang Anda masukkan belum lengkap.');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'Judul', 'required', $error_msg);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('konten', 'Konten', 'required', $error_msg);

    if ($id_pengetahuan) {
        $post = $this->mod_pengetahuan->getPengetahuan_id($id_pengetahuan);

        $data['id_pengetahuan'] = $id_pengetahuan;
        $data['id_pengguna'] = $ses_id;
        $data['judul'] = $post->judul;
        $data['konten'] = $post->konten;
        $data['tanggal'] = $post->tanggal;
        $data['url'] = $post->tanggal;
        $data['kategori'] = $post->kategori;
        $data['bagikan'] = $post->bagikan;
        $data['status'] = $post->status;
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->view('pengetahuan_edit', $data);  
    }
    else {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/profil/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000'; //kilobyte

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('url')){                
            $this->session->set_flashdata('save_gagal', 'Tipe File yang Anda Masukkan tidak sesuai.');                
            $this->view('pengetahuan_edit', $data);                
        }
        else{
            $save['id_pengetahuan'] = $id_pengetahuan;
            $save['id_pengguna'] = $ses_id;
            $save['judul'] = $this->input->post('judul');
            $save['konten'] = $this->input->post('konten');
            $save['tanggal'] = date('Y-m-d');
            $save['url'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $save['kategori'] = $this->input->post('kategori');
            $save['bagikan'] = $this->input->post('bagikan');
            $save['status'] = '1';

            $post = $this->mod_pengetahuan->savePengetahuan($save);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('save_succes', 'Pengguna baru berhasil ditambahkan.');

            redirect('pengetahuan');
        }
    }
}
```

I want when the user makes changes to the data, users are not required to upload files. but when users upload files then processes the code below will run

```
if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('url')){                
            $this->session->set_flashdata('save_gagal', 'Tipe File yang Anda Masukkan tidak sesuai.');                
            $this->view('pengetahuan_edit', $data);                
        }
```

Please help me master. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
function Ubah($id_pengetahuan) {
    $data['page_title'] = 'Ubah Pengetahuan';

    $ses_id = $this->session->id_pengguna;

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> PESAN : </strong>', '</div>');

    $error_msg = array('required' => '%s yang Anda masukkan belum lengkap.');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'Judul', 'required', $error_msg);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('konten', 'Konten', 'required', $error_msg);

    if ($id_pengetahuan) {
        $post = $this->mod_pengetahuan->getPengetahuan_id($id_pengetahuan);

        $data['id_pengetahuan'] = $id_pengetahuan;
        $data['id_pengguna'] = $ses_id;
        $data['judul'] = $post->judul;
        $data['konten'] = $post->konten;
        $data['tanggal'] = $post->tanggal;
        $data['url'] = $post->tanggal;
        $data['kategori'] = $post->kategori;
        $data['bagikan'] = $post->bagikan;
        $data['status'] = $post->status;
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->view('pengetahuan_edit', $data);  
    }
    else {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/profil/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000'; //kilobyte

         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('url')){                
            $this->session->set_flashdata('save_gagal', 'Tipe File yang Anda Masukkan tidak sesuai.');                
            $this->view('pengetahuan_edit', $data);                
        }
        else{
            $save['id_pengetahuan'] = $id_pengetahuan;
            $save['id_pengguna'] = $ses_id;
            $save['judul'] = $this->input->post('judul');
            $save['konten'] = $this->input->post('konten');
            $save['tanggal'] = date('Y-m-d');
            $save['url'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $save['kategori'] = $this->input->post('kategori');
            $save['bagikan'] = $this->input->post('bagikan');
            $save['status'] = '1';

            $post = $this->mod_pengetahuan->savePengetahuan($save);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('save_succes', 'Pengguna baru berhasil ditambahkan.');

            redirect('pengetahuan');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, the result of an error.
when the upload is also back to form updates.

Comment: basically, the process updates user data is not required to upload files. but at the moment the user to upload files, then the system will check the file type is allowed.

Comment: can you post your form view?